# Given f(z) is analytic in Domain D, is Arg|f(z)| harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Given f(z) is analytic in Domain D, is Arg|f(z)| harmonic? If yes, in which domain?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean what you actually write, then yes, obviously: $|f(z)|$ is real and non-negative, so $\operatorname{Arg} |f(z)| = 0$. (Depending slightly on what you mean by $\operatorname{Arg} 0$.)

Comment: so basically there is no restriction on domain, right? It will always be harmonic!

Comment: @de Yes, but it's identically zero - not a very exciting function... Are you sure you mean $\textrm{Arg } |f(z)|$, i.e. the argument of the *absolute* value of $f(z)$?

Comment: Yeah, this is the question. But, this will not be defined if f(z)=0

Comment: Further, if i write arg|f(z)|, the situation remains the same??

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $ arg(f(z)) $, not necessarily the principal argument and if its continuous, then its definitely harmonic. But it may not always exist. You will need each connected component of $ D $ to be simply connected and $ f(z)\ne 0 \forall z\in D $ for the existence of the argument function.